# Overriding the Default Siri UI doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm following this guide https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/sirikit/implementing-sirikit/#Overriding-the-Default-Siri-UI but *DisplaysMessage* is not working. Everything else is working and I see my custom UI as well.

Also on iOS 11 the size of the view in Siri is always the maximum size so it shows a lot of empty space while on iOS 10 it adjusts.

Am I missing something or are this bugs on Xamarin?

EDIT: My Info.plist from both Intents [image: Intent]

[image: IntentUI]

Comment: Have you followed the Configuration in Info.plist?

Comment: In the Main App? Just add a look at the Guide again and the image on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/sirikit/implementing-sirikit/#Requesting_Siri_Authorization does show a NSExtension but I don't think it is mentioned and the App is working fine it's just the UI.

Comment: The info.plist looks like mine as implemented in Swift (w/o Xamarin), and this specific intent and UI behaves as expected, so maybe that helps you eliminate one possibility.